# I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my code

Tags: java, android

The output of the Android's `logcat` informs me that an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  is thown at some point in my program :

I have set up a boolean value for the button earlier, the button is for testing purposes.

This is the code in which believe the error is located :

```
int hour = new Date().getHours();
int min = new Date().getMinutes();
int secs = new Date().getSeconds();
String date = hour + ":" + min+ ":" + secs;

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bSet = true;    
    }
});

while (date =="01:00:00" || bSet == true);
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt();
tv.setText(getResources().getString(ids[randomNumber]));
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare Strings

Comment: Use `int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(ids.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better practice change

```
while (date =="01:00:00" || bSet == true);
```

as

```
while (date.equals("01:00:00") || bSet)
```

And change `int randomNumber = rand.nextInt();`
 as `int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(ids.length);`

Comment: i thought .length was used to find a random length, but i have many strings and i would like to select a random string to display, should i still use .length?

Comment: simple answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have exception  in last line. 
Exactly here `ids[randomNumber]`

You should check random generated number, because it can be greater then ids.length. 
Use `rand.nextInt(ids.length);` It will generate random number from 0 to ids.length.

Comment: _"It will generate random number from 0 to ids.length."_ No. From 0 to ids.length-1.